# Python winamd64 image and Windows container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and want to know if there is a slim or light-sized Python winamd64 image?
In the Docker file, as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Create project directory (workdir)
WORKDIR /SMART

# Add requirements.txt to WORKDIR and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add source code files to WORKDIR
ADD . .

# Application port (optional)
EXPOSE 8000

# Container start command
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

It works well in the Linux container state, but I need my container to be Windows. I face a problem when I switch it to the Windows container, even if I change "experimental" to the true value. Therefore, I decided to use a Python winamd64 image, but all of the official images on the website are around 1 GByte. I need a small-sized Python image like (python:3.8-slim-buster) so how could I solve this problem? Or how could I change the Docker file in the first line (FROM python:3.8-slim-buster) to use a Python image that I push to my hub?